# Tile Based A* Pathfinding, but with a bomb

Tags: path-finding, a-star

I've written a simple A* path finding algorithm to quickly find a way through a tile based dungeon in which the tiles contain the information of walls.

An example of a dungeon (only 1 path for simplicity):

[image]

However now I'd like to add a variable amount of "Bombs" to the algorithm which would allow the path-finding to ignore 1 wall. However now it doesn't find the best paths anymore,

for example with use of only 1 bomb the generated path looks like the first image here: 
[image]

Edit: actually it would look like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPoAA.png

[image]

While the correct path would be the second image

The problem is that "Closed Nodes" now interfere with possible paths. Any ideas of how to tackle this problem would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can you preprocess the maps or they are totally unknown when you start the search?

Comment: At the start of pathfinding only the start and end tile and their position on the grid are known.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your "game state" will no longer only be defined by your location, but also by an integer representing the number of bombs you have left. If you're following the pseudocode of A* on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A*_search_algorithm#Pseudocode), this means you cannot simply implement the `closedSet` as a grid of booleans. It should probably be implemented as, for example, a hash map / hash set, where every entry holds the following data:

- x coordinate
- y coordinate
- number of bombs left

By visiting a certain position in the search process, you'll no longer mark just that position as closed. You'll mark the combination of position + number of bombs left as closed. That way, if later on in the same search process you run into a position where you're at the same location, but have more bombs left, you will not ignore it as closed but will actually continue searching that possibility.

Note that, if the maximum possible number of bombs is relatively low, you could also implement the `closedSet` as an array of boolean grids, where you first index by number of bombs, then by x and y coordinates to find out if a specific position is closed or not.

Comment: Hi thanks to your answer and the one from DMGregory over on http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/136509 I was able to make it work, I ended up not just adding a dimension for each bomb-use in fear of having the different paths on the dimensions block each other but creating a "completely new" dimension everytime a bomb is used, that has it's own closedlist (which is a copy of the original closed list until a bomb was used + any new nodes closed on this dimension) if later another bomb is used it creates another closedlist by copying it's parent closed node's list! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this mean that you just pretend to *not have any walls* at all?

Use A* to find the shortest path from start to end and then check how many walls you'd have to go through. If you have enough bombs, you can use the path. Otherwise, try the next longest path and so on.

By the way: you might want to check http://gamedev.stackexchange.com for questions like this one.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, however using A* there will never be a "next shortest path" for example using your method of ignoring walls the result would be [this](http://i.imgur.com/Tl6QEGz.png) 

Only the green path would be the path that is returned, The other paths are not finished since the algorithm found a path before developping them

Comment: While I could make the algorithm continue if the path wasn't valid (using more than the allotted bombs) I would run in the same problem as having closed nodes block pathing as described in the OP.

I'll also check out gamedev, thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

You need to tweak the cost function to cost something for a bomb, then run the algorithm normally with an infinite cost for a second bomb. To get the bomb approximately halfway, play about with cost function, it should probably cost about the heuristic A-B distance times the cost for an empty tile. If you have two bombs, half the cost and of course then use of three bombs costs infinite.

But don't expect very good results. A* isn't designed for that kind of optimisation.